# How to do unit test for Spring reactive handler POST method

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

```
//Mocked serverRequest like below 
MockServerRequest serverRequest = MockServerRequest.builder()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, params.get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER))
                .body(Mono.just(myUserRequest));

//Tried to verify like below, not working
StepVerifier.create(userHandler.postUserData(serverRequest))
                .assertNext(serverResponse -> assertEquals("testuser", getEntity(serverResponse).getUserId()))
                .verifyComplete();

private static UserResponse getEntity(ServerResponse serverResponse) {
        return ((EntityResponse<UserResponse>) serverResponse).entity();
    }
```

Getting this error:

> class reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust cannot be cast to class
> com.mypackage.user.model.UserResponse

how to unit test my handler post method without using WebTestClient?

Comment: Shouldn't that simply be `.body(myUserRequest)`? Otherwise you'll get a `Mono<Mono<Request>>` instead of a `Mono<Request>`

Comment: @knittl that dont work, it is expected to be Mono<myUserRequest>
Getting this error if I remove Mono
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.mypackage.user.model.UserRequest cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Mono (com.mypackage.user.model.UserRequest

Comment: This hints at the wrong cast somewhere. You cannot have both errors: "cannot cast MonoJust to UserResponse" AND "cannot cast UserRequst to Mono", unless your code performs casts in both directions (which won't work, as you can see)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full [mre] that can be copied and compiled

Comment: Note that for reactive applications, the mock request class is actually `org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest`